# how can i request a variable in my home.ctp of my cakePHP application?

Tags: php, cakephp, variables

I created a page using the MVC structure called 'sections' ( view is located in the app/views/sections folder, model in the model folder and the controller in the controller folder) when i request the variable $test, it works fine without any errors..

When i want to request this variable in my home.ctp, it provides me with an error, saying that the variable is undefined..

Is there any way in cakePHP to request this variable on any page you want it to?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "request a variable"? Request from where?

Comment: The variable that is been specified in the sectionsController 

    $this->set('test', $this->Section->findAllThreaded(null, null, 'name'));

Answer (score 1):

In the MVC stack, you need to set variables with data in your controller, and then pass them out to your view.

So in your example, you'll want to `$this->set('myvar',$item);` in your `SectionsController`, then in your view, you will be able to `echo $myvar`.

Be sure to set this in the `home()` method of your `Sections` controller, otherwise it won't be available in your `home` view.

Comment: If you are doing a find() on it, make sure to pr() the variable in the view to make sure it's not returned an empty result set!

Comment: What do you mean by 'home() method' ?

Comment: CakePHP convention states that your views are called the same as your controller methods. So I have assumed that you have a home() method in your controller, as you have a home view.
More on controllers, http://book.cakephp.org/view/50/Introduction

Comment: Well, i cant find a home() method anywhere in my app_controller.. 
Could you give me some advice on how to write it in my controller? (and which controller)?

Thnx!

Comment: Construction of controllers is really outside the scope of your question. I would recommend reading the CakePHP Book, http://book.cakephp.org/

Answer (score 0):

Standing on the shoulders of deceze's comment and DavidYell's answer, I think they've managed to scratch out a decent view of what you're trying to get to. Maybe. So with that loose understanding of what you're seeing and what you have...

By default, the `PagesController::display()` method generates the homepage view (`home.ctp`). I suspect that this is what you're talking about. That said, the variable you're setting in a method of your `SectionsController` won't be available to your homepage which is created by a different method in a different controller. If you want a variable available to all views there are several things you can do:

1. You can set the variable in your `config/core.php` file (not generally recommended)
2. You can set it in `config/bootstrap.php` if it's a constant. By that, I mean that it's a value you're going to hard code, not something dynamically generated. Whether you create the variable as a constant doesn't matter.
3. You can set in in your `AppController` in a `beforeFilter()` or `beforeRender()` method. All of your custom controllers (assuming you've followed protocol) inherit from the `AppController`. If you choose this path, make a copy of `cake/libs/controller/app_controller.php` and place it in your `app/` directory.

Those are the ways that I think will best meet your needs as I understand them.